# Spring MVC Controller Changing URL or Issuing incorrect URL

Tags: java, http, url, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I have a SpringMVC application i am not sure if its working properly. I have a registration form the url reads `http://localhost:8080/myapp/registration.htm` when i click on the query button the application is posted to the controller and the user is posted to a second page getList.htm which displays a list of results however when posted to the second page the url still reads `http://localhost:8080/myapp/registration.htm`.

When the second page is posted the user is suppose to be taken back to the first page `http://localhost:8080/myapp/registration.htm` to display the record selected form the getList.htm (this displays multiple records).

When the user is posted back to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/registration.htm` the url reads `http://localhost:8080/myapp/getList/1985121244.htm` where 1985121244 is the record number. Should the url be displaying `http://localhost:8080/myapp/registration.htm` once the user is posted back to the first page?

Also if the user tries to POST the first page after being returned form the getList.htm POST you get a HTTP 400 and the url reads `http://localhost:8080/myapp/getList/registration.htm`. The second page is appended to the url and this is not an appropriate mapping in the controller. Can someone explain what is happening here and how is it fixed.

**Edited**

Also when i first enter the application the main menu is `http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello.htm` when i click on a a href i am taken to the registration page however the page shows but the url does not change. When the href tage is clicked form the hello.htm page the Controller makes a reguest to get the registration page and returns it using `return new ModelAndView("registration");` i saw some sites that say i should use return new `ModelAndView("redirect:/registration");` However when that is used i get `404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myapp/registration"`. Any ideas anyone on what i can look at before i post code my code is alot

Comment: post code your spring code.

Comment: what parts of the code would you require me to post its alot of code do you want the controller and jsp code i will have to do a summary of it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it looks like you just return view name after login. Of course that doesn't change your url. Instead of returning view name use "redirect:/getList.htm" pointing the url you need.

Then controller which processes the getList.htm checks whether user is logged in and return proper view name.

Comment: When i use "redirect:/getList.htm" i am getting HTTP Status 404 http://localhost:8080/myapp/getList.htm"

Comment: Then you should define controller's method to process the getList.htm. Imagine after login user moved to another page and then tried to open the getList. What should happen?

Comment: I already have a url mapping with a GET method defined in the Controller for getList.htm same issue arises

Comment: If you wont mind looking at this link it has the code and a more detailed explanation of the issue i am facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456724/spring-mvc-pages-http-status-400-and-incorrect-urls